# How to create a wordpress child theme for morphology lite using my_theme_enqueue_styles()

Tags: php, css, wordpress

What is the proper way to import all of these dependencies to create a wordpress child theme?

This functions.php doesn't work

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'morphology-lite-editor-style'; 

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/editor-style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

I did create a style.css file inside a morphology-lite-child folder:

```
/*
Theme Name: morphology-lite child
Theme URI: https://wordpress.org/themes/morphology-lite/
Author: my name
Author URI: myuri.com/home
Template: morphology-lite
Version: 0.1.0
*/
```

The parent theme is 'morphology-lite' and the stylesheets are in the following file structure.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When needing to create a Child Theme for WordPress many times I use the Plugin [Child Theme Creator By Orbisius](https://wordpress.org/plugins/orbisius-child-theme-creator/).

It is very user friendly and will handle all the initial connectors then you can create your custom page templates, edit the functions file and any other modifications as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Use get_template_directory_uri() instead of get_stylesheet_directory_uri()